# How to take value from textarea to textarea with Laravel + Jquery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

How do I take value from one textarea to another with laravel and jquery ajax.
I have this files so far.
Route:

```
Route::post('/post', 'PostController@post');
```

Controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
       public function post(Request $request)
    {

 $request->json()->all();

    }
}
```

JQuery file:

```
$(function(){


 $('#insert').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
 var intrare = $('textarea#firsttextarea').val();
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '/post',
    data: {intrare: intrare},
    success: function(data){
       $('textarea#secondtextarea').val(data);
    }

 });
 });

});
```

and the html :

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="firsttextarea" rows="10" id="firsttextarea" ></textarea>

<button  id="insert" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>Insert</button>

<textarea class="form-control" name="secondtextarea" rows="10" id="secondtextarea" ></textarea>
```

When i push the button nothing happens.

Comment: What does it say in developer tools? Your controller method isn't returning a response.

Comment: nothing, that's why I am confuse it should say something

Comment: I don't have form action maybe I should use? I am new to laravel and jquery.

Comment: should i use this in the form ? <form action="/post" method="post" ?

Comment: Adrian, read the answer I've submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you're not returning a response in your Controller method.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $request)
    {      
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $request->get('intrare'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

then, add this to your head in your blade file

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and replace your JS with the below:

```
$(function() {

  // We need CSRF Token in our ajax request so we can
  // validate the POST request
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
    }
  });

  // Insert text from first textarea to the other textarea
  $("#insert").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var intrare = $("textarea#firsttextarea").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/post",
      data: { intrare: intrare },
      success: function(response) {
        $("textarea#secondtextarea").val(response.data);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, cause js xhr

Comment: i try the developer with mozilla this gives

Comment: @AdrianKlark Try the above, you need XSRF token added to your Ajax request

Comment: @AdrianKlark where did you add the meta head? Please double check you have it exactly like the above.

Comment: in head.blade.php in <head></head> section

Comment: @AdrianKlark Did you update the controller method? to `$request->get('intrare')` ? Are you sure you're typing in the first text area?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151100/discussion-between-win-and-adrian-klark).

Answer (score 2):

First problem probably can be in CSRF Verify. You can disable it if it so or add `{{ csrf_token() }}`.
Then your post action should be looks like this:

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

I checked it and it's work fine. but in textarea insert `[Object object]` because it JSON. You can add JSON.stringify in your Jquery script like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#insert').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var intrare = $('textarea#firsttextarea').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/post',
            data: {intrare: intrare},
            success: function(data){
                $('textarea#secondtextarea').val(JSON.stringify(data));
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Definitely wouldn't recommend disabling it.

Comment: @Win yes but if it for some study then this way will be faster. ofc for production you should use csrf verify